# ascending=False is not working panda dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Accending False unable to give me most data from biggest number.

```
import pandas as pd
from binance.client import Client

client = Client()
ticker_info = pd.DataFrame(client.get_ticker())
busd_info = ticker_info[ticker_info.symbol.str.contains('USDT')]
busd_info = busd_info.sort_values(by='priceChangePercent', ascending=False)
# busd_info = busd_info.priceChangePercent.max()
print(busd_info.head(60))
print(busd_info)
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe strings? What is `print (busd_info.priceChangePercent.dtype)` ?

Comment: let me try. I think it will work.

Comment: Its give me a object the what ? 

busd_info = busd_info.sort_values(by='priceChangePercent', ascending=False)
busd_info = busd_info.priceChangePercent.dtype

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you try to check what's your data types?

```py
print(busd_info.dtypes)
```

If it's not the type you want, for example, your `priceChangePercent` should be `float` type, so you can convert it first before sorting.

```py
# Convert to correct type
busd_info.priceChangePercent = bush_info.priceChangePercent.astype(float)

# Sorting 
busd_info = busd_info.sort_values(by='priceChangePercent', ascending=False)

print(busd_info)
```

Comment: It seems your answer is correct but if you see the screenshot it's the same result. 
https://prnt.sc/lIpg8nLB7grE

Comment: I think you should convert it first before sorting

Answer (score 1):

If test `dtype`:

```
print (busd_info.priceChangePercent.dtype)
object
```

It means there are not numeric values so sorted like strings in lexicographical order.

For convert to numeric use [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html) with `errors='coerce'` for convert if exist not numeric value to `NaN`s:

```
busd_info.priceChangePercent = pd.to_numeric(bush_info.priceChangePercent, errors='coerce')
```

Comment: Both answers is right. My problem was I short percentage before I convert this to a numeric value from the object.